# Are inverses of groups unique in general?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, inverse, abelian-groups

A group is a mathematical construct having closure, inverse, identity and Associativity.

I am having trouble in proving (or disproving) if the inverse of an element are unique?

I have tried to prove $b=c$ in the following cases:

Here $a$ and $b$ belong to the set and $\cdot$ is used to show the operation

1.

$$a\cdot b=e_1$$
$$a\cdot c=e_1$$

where $x\cdot e_1=x$ (right identity, *i.e.*, $e_1$ is multiplied to the right hand side to get $x$)

2. $$a\cdot b=e_2$$
   $$a\cdot c=e_2$$

$e_2\cdot x=x$ (left identity, *i.e.*, $e_2$ is multiplied to the left hand side to get $x$)

In which case and why, we can say that $b=c$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes the inverse is always unique. Suppose $x_1$ and $x_2$ are inverses of $x$. Then $(x_1 * x) * x_2 = x_1 * (x *x_2) = x_2 = x_1$

Comment: Also, your use of $e_1,e_2$ seems to indicate two distinct identities; but in a group the identity is always unique. (Can you see why?)

Comment: Yes, I am able to show that the left and right identities of Non-Abelian group are unique by using the Associativity property. For Abelian grous, they are the same.<br> However, I do not get why the two identities must be the same in general

Comment: @Curious_To_Know If a group has both left and right identities, then what is $x x^{-1}$?

Comment: What's $e_2\cdot e_1$?

Comment: xx−1 I don't know what this is. <br> But if we take $x.l^{-1}x=e_2$ and x.xr-1=e1, we get $xl^{-1}$ as $xr_{-1}$. to be equal.

Comment: e2 . e1 is I don't know. I was not able to reduce it to something.

Comment: x $x_r^{-1}$ is the real problem. I don't know how it is defined. It may either be equal to e1 or e2. If it is equal to e1, then there is no issue;One is easily able to show (by a method similar to Shaun) that both left and right inverses are unique and equal. The problem arises if we define x $x_r^{-1}$=e2 and  $x_l^{-1}$ x = e1 and I am not able to reduce it further.

Comment: You say you don't know what $e_2 e_1$ is; I think that's a good thing to settle first. (1) In your post, you wrote that $e_1$ is a right identity. Does that help you to deduce what $x \cdot e_1$ is equal to (for any given $x$)? And can you apply that to simplify $e_2 \cdot e_1$? (2) Next, I see that you also wrote that $e_2$ is a left identity. Does that help you to deduce what $e_2 \cdot y$ is equal to (for any given $y$)? And can you apply that to simplify $e_2 \cdot e_1$?  (3) Can you put together the results of (1) and (2) to deduce any further conclusion regarding $e_1$ and $e_2$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trick here is to pit two inverses $s,t$ of an element $x$ against each other. Let $e$ be the identity element.

By definition, $s\cdot x=e=x\cdot s$ and $t\cdot x=e=x\cdot t$.

We have

$$\begin{align}
s&=s\cdot e\\
&=s\cdot (x\cdot t)\\
&=(s\cdot x)\cdot t\\
&=e\cdot t\\
&=t.
\end{align}$$

Comment: But here we have shown that left and right inverses are equal. And that too when e1 is equal to e2.(better from is left inverse * no = e2 and right inverse * no. = e1). Choosing 1 of many right inverses and then equating all left inverses to these, we can show uniqueness of left inverse. Using the same we may show uniqueness of right inverse. But what if we did not take the above conditions?

Comment: I don't understand your question, @Curious_To_Know. In a group, left inverses are right inverses. Which definition of a group are you using?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include some details, @Curious_To_Know.

Comment: I have use the standard definition of groups except the fact that the left and right identities may not be equal in general i.e. x*$e_1$=x     &     $e_2$*x=x. ; where e1 and e2 may not be equal in general.

Comment: Then $e_1=e_2*e_1=e_2$, @Curious_To_Know.

Comment: If you wish to ask something else, @Curious_To_Know, please ask it in a new thread; I have answered this question as it was asked.

Comment: Thanks. I got it now @Shaun

Comment: You're welcome, @Curious_To_Know. After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).